# Angular Fullstory integration how to implement user uuid

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an angular application where I'm trying to generate some sort of identification for the user within [Fullstory](https://www.fullstory.com/).

My current implementation sets the uuid of the user to the user id that is specific to each user within the application. It's implemented like this:

```
  export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {
    FullStory.init({orgId: '****'});
    userService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(user => {
      if (user){
        FullStory.identify(user.id, {
          displayName: 'User ' + user.id,
        });
        FullStory.event('Subscribed', {
          uid_str: user.id,
          plan_name_str: 'Professional',
          plan_price_real: 299,
          plan_users_int: 10,
          days_in_trial_int: 42,
          feature_packs: ['MAPS', 'DEV', 'DATA'],
        });
      }else {
      }
        });
  }
```

Currently, after the user logs in, the fullstory session is created and associated with the given user. I'm however not sure how to create user session when the user is not logged in when it's an anonymous user. User can come to page do something and log in for example after five minutes. Is there a way how to create a new Fullstory session with random uuid user and then create another one after the user logs in or is there a different way how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `FullStory.init`, it already automatically creates an anonymous session. Calling `FS.identify` will associate the user with the previous anonymous sessions as well as the future sessions from that same user. So I believe your current code should already have achieved what you are looking for. The help article listed several best practices and does not recommend using `identify` with random uuid.

For more information here is a help article on `FS.identify`:
https://help.fullstory.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020828113-FS-identify-Identifying-users